# Do the evil spirits really exist?

Tags: jinn

Do the evil spirits really exist?

If the answer is no so what if a Muslim sees a dead person's spirit? Is this a jinn or spirit?

And what about paranormal activities?

Comment: Do you mean seeing dead person in (your) dreams? an evil spirit=jinn

Answer (score -1):

What seems in dream is neither evil jinn nor Spirit. It's an imagination produced by your mind relating to your situations. Sometimes some dreams are signs which if interpreted liberate meaningful sense but they are very rare. A Jinn or spirit has no power to interfere you while you are sleeping. A spirit of a dead person can never be observed while you are awake or sleeping because spirit of a dead person can never ever come back to earth! While Jinns can show up their self only when you are awake as they have the power to hid or reveal themselves but they don't have powers to intercept your subconscious state!

Answer (score -1):

> Do the evil spirits really exist?

No, there is no evil spirit. But If you mean spirit as soul then, a soul can be corrupted by others' influences.

> If the answer is no so what if a Muslim sees a dead person's spirit?

Generally, none can see any dead spirit because they are dead and getting punishment or in eternal peace in the life of Barzakh (Grave).
But it is possible to see them in dreams. but it can be tricks of satans, too.

> Is this a jinn or spirit?

Yes, if the dream isn't true, then, it's Jinn.

> And what is the answer of the paranormal activities?

Paranormal activities are the work of jinns.